# Are you meant to use your character unique app ID in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

In the 'identifier' field in Xcode are you meant to put the 10 character app identifier before putting com.*company.appname*?

I tried it and it gives me a code sign error, but without it it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do but all you need to have in your info plist for your bundle is this:

```
com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:identifier}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application identifier must match with identifier using which you created the certificate(One probable reason for code signing error is that identifier is not matching).
So Please confirm the identifier given in developer account is also like com.company.appname.